# Azure Function 1.x to 2.x upgrade - Issue with GetQueryNameValuePairs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have an HTTP Trigger Azure Function which is currently in 1.x. The code is as below:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Set name to query string or body data
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}
```

While trying to upgrade it to 2.x, I am getting an issue with `GetQueryNameValuePairs`

I am getting error - `'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetQueryNameValuePairs'`

Is there no support for this method in 2.0? How can this be accomplished in .net standard?

Answer (score 0):

Function runtime 1.x is on Full .Net Framework, while 2.x runs on .NET Core env and our function code targets at .NET Standard.

For this class `HttpRequestMessage`, it doesn't have `GetQueryNameValuePairs` method in .NET Standard assembly.

Migrating from 1.x to 2.x usually needs work of code modification. Since it's just a template, I suggest you delete it and recreate a Http Trigger in 2.x runtime. You may see a different template work with .NET Standard.

Comment: Do we have an equivalent for that in .net standard. I could not find anything. Or should we manually parse the query string?

Comment: @SillyJohn If you have created a http trigger template in 2.x, you can see it uses `HttpRequest req` and `req.Query["name"]`. Is this the equivalent you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that looks up query string parameters in Functions V2.x

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   if (req.Query.TryGetValue("name", out StringValues value))
   {
     return new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {value.ToString()}");
   }

   return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Functions v2 this has changed to  req.GetQueryParameterDictionary();